# Regex for BBCodes, not working if a BB Code is inside itself (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

So, for basic stuff my regex is working fine.

eg

`[b]text[/b]` becomes `<b>text</b>`

but

`[b]te[b]x[/b]t[/b]` becomes `<b>te[b]x</b>t[/b]`
ideally i want it: `<b>te<b>x</b>t</b>`

If i do a different bbcode, it works:

`[b]te[i]x[/i]t[/b]` becomes `<b>te<i>x</i>t</b>`

The reason this is an issue, is because i have a quote bbcode, and sometimes people will end up quoting someones post, which itself has quoted someone else.

The regex looks like this:

```
$str = preg_replace("/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/misS", "<b>$1</b>", $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\[(/?b)\]` and replace it with `<$1>`

Comment: I'm not sure what the benefit of this two-step solution is.  If you are willing to dispense with the requirement of matched pairs (which you have done), then this can be solved with a single very simple regex.

Comment: @dan1111 yeah..i made it too complex...but i have edited this ans before your comment..i guess ajax is not working properly in your browser..;)

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ This actually looks very good for simple bbcodes like <i> and <b>, but what if one of my bbcodes is more complex? like (example): <div><span>im a turtle and i like doing turtle things</span><br/><span>$1</span></div>

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with a regex as long as you are willing to be fairly dumb: don't worry about finding matched pairs, just replace anything that looks like an opening or closing tag:

```
$str = preg_replace("|\[(/?\w+)\]|iS", "<$1>", $str);
```

If something like that is not good enough, then a regex is not your solution.  It can't handle nested elements properly because it is not a real parser.

There is a [PHP extension for parsing BBCode](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php).  That is probably the way to go if you are interested in robust, correct parsing (caveat: haven't used it myself).

Comment: Ill have a look at that extension if i cant fix it, the problem with your solution, is cant people break the formatting of the page? if they do [b] at the end of their post, the whole page will be in bold, unless theres a solution to that too?

Comment: @Headchopperz, that is a very good point.  If you care at all about stuff like that, I suggest using the extension.  There will just be *way too many headaches* doing this with a regex.  It's not just one problem but many problems.  That's why I said, only use a regex if you are willing to have "dumb" parsing.